# How can I eliminate the use of `any` in this TypeScript mapper

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

```
type ObjectMapper = (
  obj: Record<string, string | number>,
  fn: (v: string | number, k: string, i: number) => any
) => any[];

export const objectMap: ObjectMapper = (obj, fn) =>
  Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v], i) => [k, fn(v, k, i)]);
```

The object mapper basically takes an object and a function for generating an array of entries based on value/key/index.  Sometimes I return an array of React Children, sometimes strings, sometimes numbers.  I'd like to have it so that `ObjectMapper` has a generic return type, which is the array of of the returns from the mapper function.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)?

Comment: I haven't posted this as an answer because I don't understand your implementation of `objectMap`.  It seems to be returning an object with the same keys as `obj`, not an array.  If the implementation in the Playground link in my previous comment is what you want, great.  Otherwise maybe you don't want an array?

Comment: Yes, I realized there is a mismatch between object and array.  I'm going to edit the question

Comment: So `objectMap` returns an array of key-value entries now... is that the intent?

Comment: I'm voting to close the question, since it was poorly formed.  But here's what I ended up using.  https://gist.github.com/bsgreenb/2d67f711854e916ca0918da31c89b676 It works for any object which maps to string or numeric values

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out I initially mixed the 2 use cases (returning array, and returning Record) I needed in my question.  Here's my solution for the two cases, then:

**Object map to array**

No special method is needed for this, just e.g.:

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v], i) => (
  // object->array map function here 
)
```

**Object map to object**

```
type MappableObject = Record<string, string | number>;

export function objectMap<T>(
  obj: MappableObject,
  fn:
    | ((v: string, k?: string, i?: number) => T)
    | ((v: number, k?: string, i?: number) => T)
): MappableObject {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v], i) => fn(v, k, i));
}
```

I'm sure that could be simplified, though.  Welcome any feedback/comments

Comment: Your question only mentions obj -> array; your answer to that is just "no special method is needed for this"?  So you don't care about generics and the different possible returns from `fn()`?  The question doesn't seem to talk about obj -> obj at all but you have an answer for it anyway.  I guess I'm just confused about what is being asked and answered here .

Comment: And your obj -> obj code also doesn't work since `fn(v, k, i)` is just a `T` and not a `[string, T]` as required by `Object.fromEntries()`. 

Comment: I can fix the above code to make it properly generic and return `T[]` for object-to-array and `Record<string, T>` for object-to-object, if you're interested.  I'm happy to post an answer but maybe you could fix the question to explicitly state what you're asking for?  (If you want an array of entries, then it should be something like `[string, any][]` and not `any[]`, and you should mention the object-to-object map in your question if you want an answer for it.)  Good luck!

Comment: You're right @jcalz.  I'm going to sort this out and post an update

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing since your given function returns an array, so you're returning an array of arrays.  From what you said you want to return an array of *something* when you call a function with the type `objectMap`.

It sounds like you want to take an object with properties that have string or number values and and map it's properties into another type and return an array of that type, one element for each property on the object.

```js
type ObjectMapper<T> = (
  obj: Record<string, string | number>,
  fn: (v: string | number, k: string, i: number) => T
) => T[];

export const objectMap: ObjectMapper<string> = (obj, fn) =>
  Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v], i) => fn(v, k, i));

console.log(objectMap({ name: 'jason', phone: '7125551212', age: 25}, (v, k, i) => {
  return `Returning a string for key ${k} with value ${v} at index ${i}`;
}));
```